# ng-model issue on logic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have a little issue with an `ng-model` I am working on.

First I will show the part where the `ng-model` is working properly

```
  <input type="text"
         ng-model="slip.risk"
         ng-change="riskWinCalculations(slip, 'RISKSTRAIGHT')">

  <input type="text"
         ng-model="slip.win"
         ng-change="riskWinCalculations(slip, 'WINSTRAIGHT')">

  <strong>To Win: </strong>{{straightTotalWin | currency}}

  <strong>Total Stake: </strong>{{straightTotalStake | currency}}
```

now the html where the `ng-model` is not working for me

```
  <input type="text"
         ng-change="riskWinCalculations(null, 'RISKPARLAY')"
         ng-model="riskParlay">

  <strong>To Win: </strong>{{winParlay | currency}}

  <strong>Total Stake: </strong>{{riskParlay | currency}}
```

in this controller you will see a function named `applyParlayRisk` which is giving me problems and other function named `riskWinCalculations` where the case `RISKPARLAY` is giving me problems also, the rest of them, are working like a charm

```
   applyStraightRisk = function(slip) {
      var moneyLine = _.result(_.find(slip.lines, {isSelected: '1'}), 'moneyLine');
      slip.win = RiskWikCalculations.calculateStraightBet(slip.risk, parseFloat(moneyLine, 10), true);
    }, 

   applyStraightWin = function(slip) {
      var moneyLine = _.result(_.find(slip.lines, {isSelected: '1'}), 'moneyLine');
      slip.risk = RiskWikCalculations.calculateStraightBet(slip.win, parseFloat(moneyLine, 10), false);
    }, 

   applyParlayRisk = function(parlay, riskParlay) {
      $scope.riskParlay = riskParlay;
      console.log($scope.riskParlay);
      //this logs UNDEFINED
      $scope.winParlay = riskParlay * (parlay.payoutProportion || 4.5);
    }, 

  sumStraightStakes = function(betSlip) {
      var totalStake = 0,
          totalWin = 0;
      _.each(betSlip, function(slip) {
        if (slip.risk) {
          totalStake += parseFloat(slip.risk, 10);
        }
        if (slip.win) {
          totalWin += parseFloat(slip.win, 10);
        }
      });
      $scope.straightTotalStake = totalStake;
      $scope.straightTotalWin = totalWin;
    };


    $scope.riskAll = 0;
    $scope.winAll = 0;
    $scope.riskWinCalculations = function(slip, type) {
    switch (type) {
      case 'RISKSTRAIGHT':
        applyStraightRisk(slip, slip.risk);
        break;
      case 'WINSTRAIGHT':
        applyStraightWin(slip, slip.win);
        break;
      case 'RISKPARLAY':
        applyParlayRisk($scope.currentParlay, $scope.riskParlay);
        break;
     }
     sumStraightStakes($scope.betSlip);
    };
```

so where do you think I have my mistake here ?

**UPDATE**

in a mobile app I am doing exactly the same functionality and there is working properly, look

html

```
  <button ng-click="openRiskWinKeypad(null, 'RISKPARLAY')">
     Risk: {{riskParlay}}
  </button>

  <strong>Total Stake: </strong>{{riskParlay | currency}}

  <strong>To Win: </strong>{{winParlay | currency}}
```

controller

```
applyParlayRisk = function(parlay, amount) {
      $scope.riskParlay = amount;
      $scope.winParlay = amount * (parlay.payoutProportion || 4.5);}
```

here is a little difference because I am opening a custom keypad

```
$scope.openRiskWinKeypad = function(slip, type) {
      $scope.keypad = {value: 0};
      if (type === 'RISKSTRAIGHT' && slip.risk) {
        $scope.keypad.value = slip.risk;
      }
      if (type === 'WINSTRAIGHT' && slip.win) {
        $scope.keypad.value = slip.win;
      }

      $ionicPopup.show({
         // here is where the keypad opens
      }).then(function(amount) {
        if (amount) {
          switch (type) {
            case 'RISKSTRAIGHT':
              applyStraightRisk(slip, amount);
              break;
            case 'WINSTRAIGHT':
              applyStraightWin(slip, amount);
              break;
              break;
            case 'RISKPARLAY':
              applyParlayRisk($scope.currentParlay, amount);
              break;
          }
        }
        sumStraightStakes($scope.betSlip);
      });
    };
```

**EDIT**

if I do

```
<input type="text" ng-model="riskParlay"
       ng-change="riskWinCalculations(null, 'RISKPARLAY')">
```

and

```
applyParlayRisk = function(parlay, riskParlay) {
      $scope.riskParlay = riskParlay;
      console.log($scope.riskParlay);
      $scope.winParlay = riskParlay * (parlay.payoutProportion || 4.5);
    }
```

and

```
    case 'RISKPARLAY':
      applyParlayRisk($scope.currentParlay, riskParlay);
      console.log($scope.currentParlay.name);
      break;
```

all I get is

> ReferenceError: riskParlay is not defined

Comment: these code snippets aren't even close to the same.  In the first, you are passing `$scope.riskParlay` as a parameter, in the second you are passing some other value.  `applyParlayRisk($scope.currentParlay, $scope.riskParlay);`, `applyParlayRisk($scope.currentParlay, amount);`  The first option doesn't actually make sense, as you appear to be assigning `$scope.riskParlay` to itself, since it is the parameter being passed in.

Comment: @Claies that's what I am trying to figure out, that's why the question is **issue logic**, because I have an error on my code, otherwise I will not be here.

Comment: is the `applyParlayRisk` function shared between the mobile and desktop code bases?

Comment: @Claies, nope, are functions apart, different controllers I have code for mobile, and another code for web. The mobile snippet controller has a parameter amount, which is the numbers/amount that user enter in the custom keypad I mentioned above. In the web snippet I have ```riskParlay``` which should be the value that the user enters in the input.

Comment: so then why are you passing `$scope.riskParlay` as the parameter `riskParlay`, and then in the first line, assigning it to itself, via `$scope.RiskParlay = riskParlay`?  I think you are breaking the property there.

Comment: @Claies, I already did it passing ```riskParlay``` and all I am getting is an undefined, let me update my code, just a moment.

Comment: @Claies see the **EDIT** part

Comment: well, it's not possible without seeing the entire code in a plunker or something to know for sure, but I think that @TahsisClaus is correct.  the variables that are working appear to be objects, using a `.` for the property.  the one which is not is a simple property, which is easily accidentally mismanaged due to closure issues.  Could you not put `riskParlay` on `slip`, so it would be `slip.riskParlay`?

Comment: well that wouldn't make any sense either, how would `riskParlay` ever be assigned at all in the edited scenario?

Comment: @Claies how do I assign it here ? I did ```$scope.riskParlay = riskParlay```

Comment: but it should *already* be assigned, by `ng-model`, unless something else overwrote it.  in that assignment, you are assigning `$scope.riskParlay` to some variable that who knows where it got it's value from......

Comment: I think you really should consider studying the video that is listed in the given answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell for sure since you didn't post the whole html snippet, but my guess is there is a another scope between the riskParlay input and the controller. If there is, the ng-model directive is will write the riskParlay variable on to that scope, not that the controller's scope.

Your other inputs happen to work because they have object indexing in their expression (the . operator). Ng-model expressions with that operator look up the scope hierarchy until they find a scope that has the object being indexed. This video explains it a lot better: https://thinkster.io/egghead/the-dot

Comment: They are in the same scope, everything is in the same html and in the same controller.

Comment: Many ng-directives generate a scope. ngForm, ngHide, ngShow, ngRepeat all generate scopes for instance.

Comment: the weird thing here is that I am doing the same for a mobile app, and there is working.